# Django: diffence of 4-6 seconds when executing datetime.now() at the models vs views

Tags: mysql, django, datetime, view, model

When I do:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def startExam(request):
  examCycle = ExamRecords() 
  examCycle.starttime =  datetime.datetime.now()  
  examCycle.save()
```

Saved starttime is as espected, but when i do it at the model:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
class ExamRecords(models.Model):
    starttime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

Time is delayed by 4-6 seconds.

Tried too using mysql now but the difference was still worse:

```
class ExamRecords(models.Model):
    starttime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

... so I'd just like to understand the reason for this seconds using the same python code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accidentally set the time of the server [re]starting as the default value for `starttime` field.  Remove round brackets after the `datetime.now` in the field definition:

```
starttime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

If you want to calculate the default value for the field then create a function and set this function as the `default` parameter:

```
def default_endtime():
    return datetime.datetime.now() + \
           datetime.timedelta(minutes=settings.TEST_LENGHT_MINUTES)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    starttime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    endtime = models.DateTimeField(default=default_endtime)
```

Comment: See the updated answer.  And `auto_now_add` is a historical rudiment from the times when django had no support for callables in the `default` argument.

Comment: Thank you with some big delay, catavaran :-)